# Redux with async components in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am currently developing a React Native mobile application.

I want to show the data from a database in a FlatList but two problems have come up so far:

1. I can't mapStateToProps if the data has not been fetched yet
2. The FlatList component throws an error when it is loaded given that that the data is not shown yet

I have tried to create a loading prop that will be sent set as true as soon as the component is mounting and will 'unblock' the functions that require the data; however this has not worked so far.

````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Spinner } from "../../common";
import { booksFetch } from "../../actions/BookshelfActions";

class BookshelfList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.booksFetch(); // Gets the data from the website
  }

  addBookScreen = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("bookshelfadd");
  };

  renderRow(book) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{book.book_name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  renderList() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      console.log("loading");
      return <Spinner />;
    }
    return (
      <FlatList // Shows the data on the screen. Will crash if there is no data
        data={this.props.booklist}
        renderItem={() => this.renderRow()}
        keyExtractor={(book) => book.uid}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderList()}
        <Button onPress={this.addBookScreen} title="Add Book" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  if (!this.props.loading) {
    const user_books = _.map(state.bookshelf.booklist, (val, uid) => { // Maps the data to the state. Will crash if there is no data
      return { ...val, uid };
    });
  }

  return {
    booklist: user_books || null,
    loading: state.bookshelf.loading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { booksFetch })(BookshelfList);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) default everything to empty arrays when the data is null (if you are expecting to receive an array):

```js
_.map(state.bookshelf?.booklist || [], (val, uid) => ...)
```

Note, `?` is only available depending on the version of the `babel` compiler. If you're using the latest version of React Native, it should work. If not, you'll have to do some more checks such as `state.bookshelf && state.bookshelft.booklist || []`.

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.props.booklist || []}
  ...
/>
```

You should always provide a default value or conditionally render if the data you receive might be `null`.

Comment: Thank you! I have done, this but then the _.map will expect a uid from a null array. Any suggestions on how to work around this issue?

Comment: Sorry, a little typo! I fixed it in the answer. If it's an empty array, then .map will never run on an element so it'll never expect an uid